# 指定したユーザがやりとりしたメッセージの中から、相手ユーザごとに最新の1件を取得したい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Ruby on Rails 4.2.0で実装を行なっています。
以下のようなデータ構造をもつMessageモデルがあるとします。

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: messages
#
#  id           :integer          not null, primary key
#  from_user_id :integer          not null
#  to_user_id   :integer          not null
#  content      :text             not null
#  created_at   :datetime         not null
#  updated_at   :datetime         not null
```

ここで、ユーザごとにやりとりしたメッセージの新着1件ずつを取得したいと考えています。

例えば、指定したユーザがやりとりしたメッセージの一覧は以下のような`scope`で定義できると思います。

```
scope :related_to, ->(user) { where('from_user_id = :user_id OR to_user_id = :user_id', user_id: user.id) }
```

これだとユーザごとにすべてのメッセージが取得されてしまいます。

実現したいことは、イメージとしては「`from_user_id`か`to_user_id`のどちらかについて、1ユーザあたり1件しか取得できない」という条件になると思っています。

汚い書き方をするなら、こうなると思います：

1. `related_to(user)`の`from_user_id`と`to_user_id`をマージする（配列化）
2. 配列から自分のIDを取り除く
3. `uniq`で重複を取り除く（ここで最新メッセージをやりとりしたユーザIDが取得できる）
4. 3のそれぞれ最新のメッセージを取得する

よい書き方があれば教えていただければと思います。
よろしくお願いします。

---

追記です。
ざっくりと、以下のようなコードになるかと思います。
よい書き方があれば、ぜひ回答ください。

```
module Messages
  class HeadlinesFinder
    def initialize(user)
      @user = user
      @messages = []
      @other_user_ids = []
    end

    def call
      messages = Message.order(created_at: :desc).related_to(@user)

      messages.each do |message|
        other_user_id = (message.from_user_id == @user.id) ? message.to_user_id : message.from_user_id

        unless other_user_id.in?(@other_user_ids)
          @messages << message
          @other_user_ids << other_user_id
        end
      end

      @messages
    end
  end
end
```

使い方：

```
@headlines = Messages::HeadlinesFinder.new(current_user).call
```

Comment: コードだけ見てもどういう結果を期待しているのかがわかりづらいので、「DBがこういう状態であれば、こういうアウトプットを得たい」という具体例も追記してもらえると助かります。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

なんとなくINとOUTをこちらで予想してみました。
たぶんこういうことですよね？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

SQLを活用してこんな実装を考えてみました。

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :headlines_for, ->(user) do
    where("messages.id IN (#{HEADLINES_SQL})", user_id: user.id).order(id: :desc)
  end

  HEADLINES_SQL = <<-SQL
SELECT MAX(m2.id) AS id
FROM   (SELECT m.from_user_id AS other_user_id,
               m.id
        FROM   messages m
        WHERE  m.to_user_id = :user_id
        UNION ALL
        SELECT m.to_user_id AS other_user_id,
               m.id
        FROM   messages m
        WHERE  m.from_user_id = :user_id) m2
GROUP  BY m2.other_user_id
  SQL
end
```

実装を簡略化するため、created_at順ではなく、id順で最新かどうかを判断するようにしています。
SQLiteで動作確認していますが、他のRDBMSでもいけるんじゃないかなーと思います。（たぶん）

ちなみにテストはこんな感じです。

```
# seeds.rb
User.delete_all
hiroshi = User.create!(name: 'ひろし')
hanako = User.create!(name: 'はなこ')
takashi = User.create!(name: 'たかし')

Message.delete_all
Message.create!(from_user: takashi, to_user: hanako, content: 'こんにちは、はなこ')
Message.create!(from_user: hanako, to_user: takashi, content: '何のようですか？たかし')
Message.create!(from_user: hanako, to_user: hiroshi, content: 'こんばんは、ひろし')
Message.create!(from_user: hanako, to_user: hiroshi, content: '今ちょっといいですか？')
Message.create!(from_user: hiroshi, to_user: takashi, content: 'たかし、来週ひま？')
Message.create!(from_user: hiroshi, to_user: hanako, content: '何だい、はなこ？')

# message_spec.rb
RSpec.describe Message, type: :model do
  before do
    Rails.application.load_seed
  end

  describe '::headlines_for' do
    let(:contents) do
      user = User.find_by_name user_name
      Message.headlines_for(user).map(&:content)
    end
    context 'はなこ' do
      let(:user_name) { 'はなこ' }
      it 'returns headlines' do
        expect(contents).to eq %w(何だい、はなこ？ 何のようですか？たかし)
      end
    end
    context 'たかし' do
      let(:user_name) { 'たかし' }
      it 'returns headlines' do
        expect(contents).to eq %w(たかし、来週ひま？ 何のようですか？たかし)
      end
    end
    context 'ひろし' do
      let(:user_name) { 'ひろし' }
      it 'returns headlines' do
        expect(contents).to eq %w(何だい、はなこ？ たかし、来週ひま？)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

実際にサンプルアプリケーション（画面無し、ModelとSpecのみ）も作ってみたのでよかったら自分で動かしてみてください。

https://github.com/JunichiIto/message-query-sandbox